# Add borders to side of image

Tags: photo-editing

I have a square image that I am looking to turn into a landscape sized image by adding  solid black borders to the left and right of the image (optionally with a fade to white type gradient). I know this is a really simple thing to do, but I don't know where to start.

I don't have any image software on my PC, other than Picasa. I tried looking at PicMonkey online but it didn't seem to do what I wanted.

Can someone give me some simple steps to accomplish this?

Comment: You can't do it with Pisca. Pisca does not allow pixel-level editing. Can't do it in PicMonkey either. Your first step in helping yourself is to determine what application you want to use. Instructions will be different for each application. You might play with Paint.net if are on Windows or Paintbrush for the Mac.

Comment: I'm on a PC. I'll check out Paint.net, although when I have used graphics software in the past I am overwhelmed by the complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go: [SplashUp - Online Image Editor](http://www.splashup.com/)
-Jump Right in

Splashup, formerly Fauxto, is a powerful editing tool and photo manager. With the features professionals use and novices want, it's easy to use, works in real-time and allows you to edit many images at once. Splashup runs in all browsers, integrates seamlessly with top photo-sharing sites, and even has its own file format so you can save your work in progress.

**Simple way to add border**

- Open you image in the editor.
- Make a new empty background layer (or copy the image to a new layer)
- Increase the canvas size of the bottom layer as much as you require, use this new area to make a border for your image.

Comment: That looks promising! I'll give it a try this evening.

Comment: I hope it's helpful, it's nowhere near PS but can be handy when you don't have an editor software on you machine...:)